# Does Google App Engine's git Push-to-Deploy also work with git submodules?

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm, git-submodules, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've got an appengine Python app which takes advantage of [endpoints-proto-datastore](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/). I did install endpoints-proto-datastore using:

git submodule add https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore

It does work when I deploy my app through PyCharm (using Google Appengine Python SDK).
It does not work when I push to google's repository (Push-to-Deploy). When using Push-to-Deploy I get the following log message:

ImportError: No module named endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb

Do I have to download the endpoints_proto_datastore library and unzip it in the root directory to get Push-to-Deploy working? I wanted to be up-to-date, that's why I did use the git submodule.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this does not work as stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9676)