# Pushing git repo (with submodules) to google app engine

Tags: php, git, google-app-engine, github, git-submodules

I have a project structure based on Laravel, versioned in Git, with various Git submodules (implemented using Composer) that I'd like to deploy/push to Google App Engine via Git. I've searched the internet for days and have tried countless tricks with recursive submodule init/updates, etc, but however I'm not having any luck.

Submodules are stuck as "references" but don't push remotely.

Is this honestly not possible?

**I'm aware of previous posts / questions ([circa 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905918/does-google-app-engines-git-push-to-deploy-also-work-with-git-submodules)) that mention you can't deploy submodules to Google App Engine, but I was wondering if that hasn't changed or if someone hasn't figured out a workaround?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google App Engine's git Push-to-Deploy also work with git submodules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905918/does-google-app-engines-git-push-to-deploy-also-work-with-git-submodules)

Comment: @cybermonkey Please see my original post, as it clearly states that it is over 2 years old and not entirely resolved.

Comment: The other post is 11 days old not 2 years old. The 12 on the date refers to the day (January 12), not 2012. You can confirm by checking the "asked" property up in the right-hand side of a question.

Comment: @MichaelK Correct, the stackoverflow post is only 11 days old, the answer within that post (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9676) is about two years old. I should have specified. Apologies.

Not going to lie, I might have confused them... but the fact is the issue has gone a long time without new information. I've already consulted other threads on this issue for updates, so I'll probably delete this.